# List of files through REST from ReactJS is empty in Spring application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, rest, spring-boot

In a Spring application I expose a controller through REST with the following code, but List  files is always empty.
What is the problem?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadMultipleFiles", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_MIXED_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity uploadMultipleFiles(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserPrincipal principal,
                                          @RequestPart String collection,
                                          @RequestPart (value="files", required = true) final List <MultipartFile> files) { 
Some logic... 
}
```

In React.JS I send the request with this code:

```
uploadFiles(e) {

    const uploadRequest = {
        collection: "prova"
    };
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('collection', new Blob([JSON.stringify("some value from form")], {
        type: "application/json"
    }));


    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.files.size; i++) {
        formData.append('files', this.state.files[i]);
    }

    uploadPhotos(formData)
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

uploadPhotos method is the following:

```
export function uploadPhotos(photoData) {
  return request({
    url: API_BASE_URL + "/photo_submit/uploadMultipleFiles",
    method: 'POST',
    body: photoData
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to upload files one by one, show a success/fail for each file. Otherwise you would have to zip/archive a whole bunch of files, and unzip them on the other end, and it is more error prone if one file is bad then the whole upload might not work.